# How to extend a Typescript comparator's type signature to handle sorting by nested object properties?

Tags: typescript

I wrote a function that works like this:

```
arr.sort(alphabeticallyBy("name"))
```

With a signature of:

```
<T extends string>(prop: T) => (a: Partial<Record<T, string>>, b: Partial<Record<T, string>>) => number
```

How could I extend this such that `T` could be an arbitrarily nested prop of `a` and `b`?

Perhaps used like:

```
arr.sort(alphabeticallyBy(["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"]))
//alternatively
arr.sort(alphabeticallyBy("prop1.prop2.prop3"))
```

Comment: Are you just looking for typings?  If so then maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N5jz9m) will work for you.  I can write that up as an answer if it meets your  needs.  If it doesn't meet your needs then please [edit] to include a [mre] with enough code to demonstrate the unmet use case.

Comment: This does meet my needs, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you want `alphabeticallyBy()` to take [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of keys, corresponding to a path to a `string` property in your array elements.  That is, given the following array:

```
declare const arr: Array<
  { prop1: { prop2: { prop3: string; prop4: number }; prop5: boolean }; prop6: Date }
>;
```

you want the following to succeed because `arr[i].prop1.prop2.prop3` is a `number`:

```
arr.sort(alphabeticallyBy("prop1", "prop2", "prop3")); // okay
```

but the following should fail because `arr[1].prop1.prop2` is not a `number`:

```
arr.sort(alphabeticallyBy("prop1", "prop2")); // error!
```

---

If so we can write a recursive utility type called `DeepRecord<K, V>` where `K` is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of property keys, and where `V` is the property value type at the path indicated by `K`.  Like this:

```
type DeepRecord<K extends PropertyKey[], V> =
    K extends [infer K0 extends PropertyKey, ...infer KR extends PropertyKey[]] ?
    { [P in K0]: DeepRecord<KR, V> } : V
```

Essentially we're using a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) and [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to shift a key `K0` off the beginning of the `K` tuple to leave the rest of it, `KR` and evaluating to the equivalent to `Record<K0, DeepRecord<KR, V>>`.  And if the tuple is empty, the base case is just `V`.

And now `alphabeticallyBy()` can use that instead of `Record<T, string>` (not sure why you had `Partial` in there but you can add `?` to `DeepRecord` if you want):

```
declare function alphabeticallyBy<K extends PropertyKey[]>(...keys: K):
    (a: DeepRecord<K, string>, b: DeepRecord<K, string>) => number;
```

Let's test it out:

```
const s = alphabeticallyBy("prop1", "prop2", "prop3");
/* const s: (
    a: { prop1: { prop2: { prop3: string; }; }; },
    b: { prop1: { prop2: { prop3: string; }; }; }
  ) => number */
```

Looks good.  The type of `s` expects objects where `a.prop1.prop2.prop3` and `b.prop1.prop2.prop3` are `string`s.  The above `arr.sort()` commands behave as desired as well.

In case it matters, this also allows you to pass in *zero* keys, in which case `a` and `b` must each be just `string`, so that you can do this:

```
["a", "b", "c"].sort(alphabeticallyBy()) // okay
```

It is possible to prohibit this by making `K extends [PropertyKey, ...PropertyKey[]]>` instead of `K extends PropertyKey[]`, but I don't think it hurts anything to allow it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgEoQMYHsBOATAPAaSggA9gIA7LAZygAUM1INQ8IQBtAXQBooA1APigBeAFBRxUAsVIVqbAJZkAZhAySADIRLkqteo2aseAOlOKVavIi0zddBqsPsOHKAH4xEgN5Q2NKIoaHABcsPBIqJi4VjwCUAC+UKG8IiJYqAA2AIYY0EoArmQowPJoZFBZGWAAFlkARhAlKJUZIABCIPg2OtT2BiAszvwAFKbGANaslKF4AJTBnuLDWaFwCMjo2Pg8lMAYigDm-Dx1q+EbUdtQu-tkR7PCgmT5ALYNGADcqeko2blQ6DIuwqGAwoQAgqCsp0fGB9ABGUKw-QAJiRUDhDAAzKEbocPhj9AAWULPN6qBIEzFgACsoTqaDQGQgWXK8Sp+gAbKssqQEvxUoDgdQhBUqrUGk0Wu0QMMAETU+FyngK1HKqCq7Fy2ZfAD0ACoAWVhaFhosKujFZbUdbsbi9vjKU74lxzacoMiGIiPYSGGifdScdcHXcCeznZ4HkInq93lB9brUiIchhjJRMMBluL6o15M0Mq0OvLFerNWAUaXA9qdVBdbqoGhxtDk6C0xmszUc1KCzLiwjK2rZjW64RQZgAIRQVJsOVZUt1UsoOUcNtMDsS3P5wuyoe1+uN5tAA)